# How to search and return 1 (or 0) if each member in list A is (or not) in list B

Tags: python-3.6

I have two lists A (16 members) and B (3 members). I want to check:
If a member in A is in B, return 1.
If a member in A is not in B, return 0.
My code does not work. Can you please help me to correct it?

```
A = list((x/4, y/4, 0.0) for x in range(0, 4) for y in range(0, 4))
B = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.25, 0.0], [0.0, 0.5, 0.0]]
v = []
for i in range(0, len(A)):
    for j in B:
        if A[i] == j:
            v[i] = 1
        else:
            v[i] = 0
print (v)
```

Output

```
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension,
if you modify A to have lists instead of tupels.

```
A = list([x/4, y/4, 0.0] for x in range(0, 4) for y in range(0, 4))
B = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.25, 0.0], [0.0, 0.5, 0.0]]

print([int(x in B) for x in A])
```

Comment: Sorry but it prints wrong output. [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].

Comment: @Binh Thien, it works correctly and outputs: [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] Read the desceription of the answer as well please. you need to modify A slightly. If you do not want to change A you need to change the list comprehension to: print([int(list(x) in B) for x in A]) but it will all in all be slower than to initilaize A differently. The main problem is that you try to compare tupels (in A) with lists (in B).

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is overly complicated, and the way you have it written, won't work as v would need to be initialized to the length of a to access the index.

```
A = list((x/4, y/4, 0.0) for x in range(0, 4) for y in range(0, 4))
B = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.25, 0.0], [0.0, 0.5, 0.0]]
v = []
for item in A:
    if list(item) in B:
        v.append(1)
    else:
        v.append(0)
```

Output:

```
> v
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```